# Do something when any one class listed in an array is clicked

Tags: jquery, arrays

What I'm trying to do: when an element with any class listed in an array is clicked, the class (and only that class) should be passed to a function.

I know well that the below is very incorrect, but I hope that it will illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var arr = ['.clickable-1', '.clickable-2', '.clickable-3', '.clickable-4', '.clickable-5'];

$(arr).click(function(){
    alert('this class got clicked: ' + $(this).prop('class'));
});
```

Comment: Elements don't have a `class` property. They have a `class` attribute or a `className` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) selector string from your array...

```
$(arr.join(',')).on('click', function() {
    console.log('this class got clicked:', this.className);
})
```

---

Note that if the element has multiple classes, ie

```
<button class="clickable-1 clickable-2 something-else and-another">
    Click me
</button>
```

They will all be shown in the `className` property.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join your array into one string to get the `jQuery` selector works.

You may also want to use `$.inArray` to check if the class exists in the Classes array (read more: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

It may be necessary to convert class attr from the element into a classes array to test one by one to support multi-classes on elements.

```
var Classes = ['.clickable-1', '.clickable-2', '.clickable-3', '.clickable-4', '.clickable-5'],
    SelectorString = Classes.join(",");

$(SelectorString).on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $thisClasses = $this.attr("class").split(" "),
        Index = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < $thisClasses.length; i++) {
    Index = $.inArray("." + $thisClasses[i], Classes);
    if (Index >= 0) break;
  }
  alert(Index);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x59w2oux/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. It work for me.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
 $("#container").append("<div class='createDiv'>" + i + "</div>");
}

$(".createDiv").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr("data-index", i);
  $(this).addClass("dataindex"+i);
});

$(".createDiv[data-index='" + 4 + "']").addClass("selected");

$('.createDiv').on("click",function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("dataindex3")){
           alert("Hai");
           multiply(2,2);
         }
         else{
            alert("welcome");
         }
});

var multiply = function(x,y){
  return x * y;
};
```

```css
.createDiv {
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #800;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it:

1. Using multiple selector e.g: `$( "div, span, p.myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" )` ([Refferences](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/))
2. Using `^` e.g: `$("[title^='Tom']").hide()`

---

**JQuery Selector Techniques :**

Taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

- `*` : Select all elements. Example: `$("*")`
- `#id` : Select the element base on `id`. Example: `$("#lastname")`
- `.class` : Select some element base on `class`. Example: `$(".intro")`
- `.class,.class,#id` : Select multiple element. Example: `$(".intro,.demo,div,#emp01")`
- `tagName` : Select element base on html tag-name. Example: `$("div")`
- `:first` : Select first element. Example: `$("p:first")`
- `:last` : Select the last element. Example: `$("p:last")`
- `:even` : Select even elements. Example: `$("tr:even")`
- `:odd` : Select odd elements. Example: `$("tr:odd")`
- etc.